# Adding new units to a Keras model layer and changing their weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a project that requires me to add new units to the output layer of a neural network to implement a form of transfer learning. I was wondering if I could do this and set the units' weights using either Keras or TensorFlow.

Specifically I would like to append an output neuron to the output layer of the Keras model and set that neuron's initial weights and bias.

Comment: Are you wanting to append to the output vector and then use this an input to a new NN?

Comment: no; my goal is only to append an output unit

Comment: Could you be more specific about your aim/intentions?

Comment: Yes, I agree with Dom. Could you please be more specific. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stumbled upon the answer to my own question. Thanks everyone for the answers/comments.

https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/

The first few lines of this source detail how to load and set weights.
Essentially, appending an output neuron to a Keras model can be accomplished by loading the old output layer, appending the new weights, and setting weights for a new layer. Code is below.

```
# Load weights of previous output layer, set weights for new layer
old_layer_weights = model.layers.pop().get_weights()
new_neuron_weights = np.ndarray(shape=[1,bottleneck_size])

# Set new weights

# Append new weights, add new layer
new_layer = Dense(num_classes).set_weights(np.append(old_layer_weights,new_neuron_weights))
model.add(new_layer)
```

Comment: How many new classes do you have? And the accuracy of the model is good after the "re-training"? I'm trying to do something like this but with about 300 new classes. But I'm removing the output layer and creating a new one with the number of neurons to handle the new classes too. And I'm struggling because the position of the classes is different in the two output layers (training and re-training). And I use the encoder position to get the class name that has the best result in the softmax. So I don't have sure if it's the correct correspondent class. Do you know how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

You could add new units to the output layer of a pre-trained neural network. This form of transfer learning is said to be called `using the bottleneck features of a pre-trained network`. This could be implemented both in tensorflow as well as in Keras.

Please find the tutorial in Keras below:
https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Also, find the tutorial for tensorflow below:

https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/08_Transfer_Learning.ipynb

Hope this helps!