# How to change input shape in keras

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, predict

I had downloaded a .h5 file from GitHub and wanted to make predictions from it. I executed the following code:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('img.jpg')
img = np.array(im)

model = load_model('model_weight.h5')

a = model.predict(img)
print(a)
```

and got the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 4096 but received input with shape [None, 300, 3]
```

Here is the model summary:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 4096)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 34)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 4096)         0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)         (None, 34, 256)      1940224     input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 128)          524416      dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                   (None, 34, 256)      525312      embedding_1[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_1 (RepeatVector)  (None, 34, 128)      0           dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDistrib (None, 34, 128)      32896       lstm_1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 34, 256)      0           repeat_vector_1[0][0]            
                                                                 time_distributed_1[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                   (None, 1000)         5028000     concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 7579)         7586579     lstm_2[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 15,637,427
Trainable params: 15,637,427
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 4096) for input Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 4096), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 300, 3).
```

I know that I have to reshape it but don't know how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check the input shape of the model using, `model.summary()`

Comment: done, but how do i change the shape?

Comment: was this model meant to work with pictures?

Comment: Simialr question is present, hope this helps! [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385223/adding-new-units-to-a-keras-model-layer-and-changing-their-weights)

Comment: yes it was made to work with images

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the model accepts square image(where the width and height is equal), the image inputs should be of size (64, 64) and with 1 channel. You can use the following steps to use the model for prediction with images

1. convert the image from RGB to grayscale
2. Resize the image to (64, 64)
3. Reshape the image to (1, 4096)
4. Feed it to the network.

```py
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('img.jpg').convert('L') # Grayscale conversion
im = im.resize((64, 64)) # Resizing to neccessary size. 
img = np.array(im).reshape(1, 4096)  

model = load_model('model_weight.h5')

sentence = np.zeros((1, 34));
sentence = model.predict([img, sentence])
print(sentence)
```

#### Generation of sentence

```py
stop_token_index = 0;  

i = 0;

sentence = np.zeros((1, 34));
while i < sentence.shape[-1]:
    next_word = np.argmax(model.predict([img, sentence]).squeeze())
    if next_word == stop_token_index:
        break
    sentence[0][i] = next_word
    i += 1
print(sentence)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I already knew. I knew that I need to resize and reshape it but I don't know how?

Comment: AssertionError: Could not compute output Tensor("dense_3/Identity:0", shape=(None, 7579), dtype=float32

Comment: Btw, there are two inputs to the network. I think the second input is not image.

Comment: What is the second input? I only put in the image

Comment: The second input, it looks like sequential data. This could be a sentence for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219384/discussion-between-amay-agarwal-and-mitiku).